# C Sharp MysqlBulkInsert vs Muplitple Insert Query

Tags: c#, mysql, bulkinsert, bulkloader

In a new company (schema may change), I have a table that will occasionally receive a bulk insert (10k - 200k Rows that MAY contain duplicates) from a parsed csv file. What would be the best approach for this?

Currently I do the following: `Insert Into table (Fields) Values (Values) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Set <Primary Key> = <Primary Key>` which takes too long especially as the number of records to be inserted increases.

The two options I'm aware of are

1) `INSERT INTO table (Fields) VALUES (Values),(Values),(Values)....`

Concerns:

- Paramaterizaion, will I have to declare thousands of command parameters to avoid sql injection?
- Duplicate Keys, is there a way to avoid the command failing when a duplicate primary key is added in the mix

2) Use `MySqlBulkLoader`

Concerns:

- Column Mapping: From what I've read the csv needs to be generated with the fields in the same order as in the table (assuming a simple `DESCRIBE tablename` will give me the correct order). Since the company is new, and the table structure HAS already changed. I don't want to forget to update the code and have my data integrity compromised.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One options is to use [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) with REPLACE syntax. REPLACE syntax will replace existing rows with input rows for rows that have the same value for a primary key or unique index in an existing row

Example:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/your_data.csv' REPLACE 
INTO TABLE your_table (column1, column2, ...)
```

As you say, your db schema will frequently change. You can read the list of columns from a configuration. That way you don't have to change your code going forward when something changes in your db schema.

Comment: Thanks, I'll read up on the LOAD DATA INFILE with REPLACE. I don't mind changing the code, what i'm worried about is if a column gets added or replaced that the bulkload will still execute the query on the different column.

Comment: Correct. As I said, you can have the list of columns in an order in a configuration file. So when the query will execute it will take correct number of columns and order.